# c++ threaded db class memory mixup

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I've been working on a project that accepts data from various hosts and injects it into a database. This project is threaded via boost::thread, and uses mysql++ to perform the actual database injections.

Lately, I've been having a serious problem with my threads grabbing incorrect information. 
For example:
thread A will receive data from server foo.b.bar.foobar.com and will determine it's hostname correctly, and it's host shortname to be foo.bar, and thread B will receive data from server fi.b.ban.foobar.com and determine it's hostname correctly, and that it's host shortname is fi.ban. All of that happens, no problem.

Then it get's handed off to the database module, and the next I see is something like "INSERT INTO foo_servers VALUES( 'foo.b.bar.foobar.com', 'fi.ban',..." being passed to mysql as a string.

All servers send their data every five minutes, so every five minutes, about 1k or so threads get created, and that is always when I start to see the problem occur.

Here is the database class header:

```
// db.h
// MySQL database connections and DB search/parsing.
#ifndef __DBASE_H
#define __DBASE_H
// database conection details go here
//#include"serial.h"
class dbase{
public:
    dbase();
    void runQuery();
    bool runDriveQuery( const std::vector<std::string> &qvec );
    bool getQueryData( const std::string &Frstate, const std::string &Fstype, const std::string &Fsite, const std::string &Fhost, const std::string &Fatype, const std::string &Fsstate, const std::string &Fanum, const std::string &Fshanme, const std::string &Fmac, const int &vfill, const int &dnum );
private:
    void updateServer();
    void inServer();
    bool checkExists( const std::string &data, const std::string &table, const std::string &field, const std::string &f2, const std::string &d2 );
    void storeQueryData( const std::string &fsval, const int &posid ); // written
    std::vector<std::string> inval;
    std::string getLocFromSite( const std::string &site );
    void insert( const std::string &qstring );
    void update( const std::string &qquery );
};
extern dbase thread;
#endif
```

here is dbase.cpp:

```
// db.h
// MySQL database connections and DB search/parsing.
// the final step of the data flow - everything ends up in an indexable mysql database in this module.
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<string>
#include<mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include<vector>
#include<iomanip>
#include"dbase.h"
#include"log.h"
bool dbase::runDriveQuery( const std::vector<std::string> &qvec ) {
bool ex = checkExists( qvec[0], "gd_drives", "host_shortname", "drive_label", qvec[1]);
std::stringstream qqquery;
if( ex ) {
qqquery << "UPDATE `" << dbname << "`.`gd_drives` SET spool_number=" << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[2];
qqquery << ", drive_status=" << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[3] <<", spool_status=" <<mysqlpp::quote_only;
qqquery << ", pending_sectors=" << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[6];
qqquery << ", reallocated_sectors=" << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[7];
qqquery << ";";
std::string fquery = qqquery.str();
qqquery.str("");
GDLogger.log( fquery, 1 );
update( fquery );
return true;
}
else {
qqquery << "INSERT INTO `" << dbname << "`.`gd_drives` VALUES ( " << mysqlpp::quote_only << "Hard Drive";
qqquery << ", " << "'" << qvec[0] << "/" << qvec[1] << "', " << mysqlpp::quote_only << inval[5];
qqquery << ", " << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[0] << ", " << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[1];
qqquery << ", " << mysqlpp::quote_only << "0";
qqquery << ", " << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[2];
qqquery << ", " << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[3];
qqquery << ", " << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[5] << ", " << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[4];
qqquery << ", " << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[6] << ", " << mysqlpp::quote_only << qvec[7];
qqquery << ", " << mysqlpp::quote_only << "0" << ", '1'";
qqquery << ");";
std::string ffquery = qqquery.str();
qqquery.str("");
GDLogger.log( ffquery, 1 );
insert( ffquery );
return true;
}
}
void dbase::runQuery() {
    GDLogger.log( "runQuery() called.", 0 );
    bool ex = checkExists( inval[1], "gd_servers", "hostname", "0", "0" );
    if ( ex == true ) {
        updateServer();
    }
    else {
        inServer();
    }
    GDLogger.log( "runQuery() completed.", 0 );
}
bool dbase::checkExists( const std::string &data, const std::string &table, const std::string &field, const std::string &f2, const std::string &d2 ) { // check if the received data matches anything already in the database
    GDLogger.log( "checkExists() called.", 0 );
    GDLogger.log ( "Checking if host already in Database...", 1 );
    mysqlpp::Connection con3( false );
    if ( con3.connect( dbname, dbhost, dbuser, dbpass ) ) {
        std::stringstream queryss;
        queryss<< "SELECT " << field << " FROM `" << dbname << "`.`" << table << "` WHERE " << field << " = " << mysqlpp::quote_only << data;
        if( f2 == "0" ) {
            queryss << ";";
        }
        else {
            queryss << "AND " << f2 << "=" << mysqlpp::quote_only << d2 << ";";
        }
        std::string qstr = queryss.str();
        GDLogger.log( qstr, 1 );
        mysqlpp::Query query = con3.query( qstr );
        mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = query.store();
        std::stringstream res1;
        for ( std::vector<mysqlpp::Row>::iterator it= res.begin(); it != res.end(); ++it ) {
            mysqlpp::Row row = *it;
            res1 << row[0];
        }
        std::string result = res1.str();
        GDLogger.log( result, 1 );
        if ( result == inval[1] ) {
            GDLogger.log( "Host exists in Database.", 1 );
            return true;
        }
        else {
            GDLogger.log( "Host does not exist in Database.", 1 );
            return false;
        }
    }
    GDLogger.log( "checkExists() completed.", 0 );
}
void dbase::updateServer() {
    std::stringstream uss;
    uss<< " UPDATE `" << dbname << "`.`gd_servers` SET asset_type=" << mysqlpp::quote_only << inval[0] << ", recover_status=" << mysqlpp::quote_only << inval[10] << ", gc_status=" << mysqlpp::quote_only << inval[11] << ", var_fill=" << mysqlpp::quote_only << 0 << ", open_ticket=" << mysqlpp::quote_only << "0" << ", last_report = NOW() WHERE hostname = " << mysqlpp::quote_only << inval[1] << ";";
    std::string upstr = uss.str();
    GDLogger.log( upstr, 1 );
    update( upstr );
}
void dbase::update( const std::string &qquery ) { // update the selected entry in the database
    GDLogger.log( "update() called.", 0 );
    GDLogger.log( "Updating database entry.", 1 );
    mysqlpp::Connection con2( false );
    if ( con2.connect( dbname, dbhost, dbuser, dbpass ) ) {
        mysqlpp::Query query = con2.query( qquery );
        mysqlpp::SimpleResult res = query.execute();
        if ( res ) {
            GDLogger.log( "Record updated sucessfully.", 1 );
        }
        else {
            GDLogger.log( "Error updating record.", 2 );
        }
    }
    else {
        GDLogger.log( "Error establishing connection to database.", 3 );
    }
    GDLogger.log( "update() completed.", 0 );
}
std::string dbase::getLocFromSite( const std::string &site ) { // use the site that is transmitted to determine what the region is
    GDLogger.log( "getLocFromSite() called.", 0 );
    mysqlpp::Connection conn( false );
    if ( conn.connect( dbname, dbhost, dbuser, dbpass ) ) {
        std::stringstream lfs;
        lfs<< "SELECT srg_code FROM `" << dbname << "`.`gd_sites` WHERE site_name = " << mysqlpp::quote_only << site << ";";
        std::string loc = lfs.str();
        GDLogger.log( loc, 1 );
        mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query( loc );
        if (mysqlpp::StoreQueryResult res = query.store() ) {
            std::stringstream res1;
            for ( std::vector<mysqlpp::Row>::iterator it= res.begin(); it != res.end(); ++it ) {
                mysqlpp::Row row = *it;
                res1 << row[0] << std::endl;
            }
            std::string result = res1.str();
            GDLogger.log( result, 1 );
            return result;
        }
        if ( conn.errnum() ) {
            GDLogger.log( "Error Received in fetching a row.", 2 );
            return "ERR";
        }
        else {
            GDLogger.log( "Unknown Error Occurred or Unhandled Exception.", 3 );
            return "ERR";
        }
    }
    else {
        GDLogger.log( "Unable to connect to database!", 4 );
        return "ERR";
    }
    GDLogger.log( "getLocFromSite() completed.", 0 );
}
void dbase::inServer() {
    std::stringstream iss;
    iss<< "INSERT INTO `" << dbname << "`.`gd_servers` VALUES( ";
    for( int i = 0; i < 13; i++ ) {
        iss << mysqlpp::quote_only << inval[i] << ", ";
    }
    iss << mysqlpp::quote_only << "0" << ", NOW() );";
    std::string is = iss.str();
    GDLogger.log( is, 1 );
    insert( is );
}
void dbase::insert( const std::string &qstring ) { // insert server info into the mysql database (only if not already present)
    GDLogger.log( "insert() called.", 0 );
    mysqlpp::Connection conn( false );
    if ( conn.connect( dbname, dbhost, dbuser, dbpass ) ) {
        mysqlpp::Query query = conn.query( qstring );
        mysqlpp::SimpleResult res = query.execute();
        if( res ) {
            GDLogger.log( "Data inserted successfully.", 1 );
        }
        else {
            GDLogger.log( "Failed to add data to database.", 2 );
        }
    }
    else {
        GDLogger.log( "Failed to connect to database. Please ensure mysql is running, and that your credentials are correct.", 3 );
    }
    GDLogger.log("insert() completed.", 0 );
}
bool dbase::getQueryData( const std::string &Frstate, const std::string &Fstype, const std::string &Fsite, const std::string &Fhost, const std::string &Fatype, const std::string &Fsstate, const std::string &Fanum, const std::string &Fshname, const std::string &Fmac, const int &vfill, const int &dnum ) {
    GDLogger.log( "getQueryData() called.", 0 ); // takes all the deserialized data from the serial class and sorts them into containers in preparation of db injection
    std::string Fshorthost = Fshname; // host shortname
    std::string Floc = getLocFromSite( Fsite ); // location, queried from database based on string
    std::string FOrt = "false"; // true/false value for whether there is an open RT for the server. default is false.
    std::stringstream ssfill;
    ssfill << vfill; // /ivar fill percentage
    std::string Fvfill = ssfill.str();
    std::stringstream ssdnum;
    ssdnum << dnum; // number of hard drives
    std::string Fdnum = ssdnum.str();
    std::string uid= ""; // queried from database, default is 0;
    if ( Fstype == "r" || Fstype == "h" || Fstype == "t" ) {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << Fstype << mysqlpp::quote << "_server";
        std::string sstype = ss.str();
        storeQueryData( sstype, 4 );
    }
    else {
        storeQueryData( Fstype, 4 );
    }
    int num = 5; // this is temporary until I write it's hook in the serial class.
    std::stringstream anum1;
    anum1 << num;
    GDLogger.log( "Retrieving values for storage in database.", 1 );
    std::string tanum = anum1.str(); // storing values in a vector for easier access
    storeQueryData( Fatype, 0 );
    storeQueryData( Fhost, 1 );
    storeQueryData( Fshorthost, 2 );
    storeQueryData( uid, 3 );
    storeQueryData( Fsite, 5 );
    storeQueryData( Floc, 6 );
    storeQueryData( Fmac, 7 );
    storeQueryData( Fdnum, 8 );
    storeQueryData( tanum , 9 );
    storeQueryData( Frstate, 10 );
    storeQueryData( Fsstate, 11 );
    storeQueryData( Fvfill, 12 );
    storeQueryData( FOrt, 13 );
    GDLogger.log( "getQueryData() completed.", 0 );
}
void dbase::storeQueryData( const std::string &fsval, const int &posid ) {
    GDLogger.log( "storeQueryData() called.", 0 );
    inval[posid] = fsval;
}
dbase::dbase() { // overrides default constructor for dbase class
    GDLogger.log( "Initializing Database Module.", 1 );
    GDLogger.log( "dbase() called.", 0 );
    // initialize the size of the query data storage vector
    inval.resize(16);
    // getQueryData(); // retrieve data to be entered into the database
}
dbase thread;
```

And here is where the thread is created:

```
void server( boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port ) {
    tcp::acceptor a( io_service, tcp::endpoint( tcp::v4(), port ) ); // starts
    for( ; ; ) {
        socket_ptr sock( new tcp::socket( io_service ) ); // creates a new socket for every connection and accepts
        a.accept( *sock );
        boost::thread t( boost::bind( session, sock ) ); // starts session in a new thread
     }
}
```

What happens between thread creation and it being passed off to the database module all passes the validation checks I built into said modules, but once it enters the database module, it's like it's getting data from other threads... or something. I've been combing through this code for weeks and I simply don't know what's happening. The only shared memory between threads if socket_ptr, which is a pointer to the original frame buffer that's being processed, which only gets referenced once and then discarded...

Edit: IF I try to instantiate dbase just inside it's thread, It refuses to link, saying undefined reference. Here the place where it is instantiated:

```
bool handle_data( std::vector<int>& buffer_data ) { // data handling happens hhere
    GDLogger.log( "handle_data() called.", 0 );
    try {
        dbase thread; // dbase instantiates here
        boost::system::error_code ec; // declare an error object ot collect exceptions
        ser.readBits( buffer_data ); //read from buffer into saod object
        std::vector<int> dbuff;
        dbuff.resize(616);
        if( buffer_data.size() >=616 ) {
            //ser.readDVec( dbuff );
            for( int i = 0; i < 576; i++ ) {
                dbuff[i] = ser.Sdbits[i];
             }
         }
         int ddnum = ser.Sdnum;
         std::string dshname = ser.Sshname;
         ddrive dd( ddnum, dshname, dbuff ); // drive module instantiates here
         bool dsvalidated = ser.deSerialize(); // deserialize data
         if(!dsvalidated) { // self explanatory
             GDLogger.log( "Deserialized data validation returned as false.", 3 );
        }
        else { // I hate this function. Reads from the serial object to the DB object.
            thread.getQueryData( ser.Srstate, ser.Sstype, ser.Ssite, ser.Shname, ser.Satype, ser.Sservices, ser.Sanum, ser.Sshname, ser.Smac, ser.Svarfill, ser.Sdnum ); // handing all the data off to the database module.
            thread.runQuery(); // runs all the queries necessary to update or insert
            dd.readDriveData( dbuff );
        }
        if( !ec ) {
            GDLogger.log( "handle_data() call completed without error.", 0 ); // if ec is still empty, we're done!
            return true;
         }
         else {
              GDLogger.log( "handle_data() call unsuccsessful, errors occurred.", 3 ); // things broke~somewhere~, but not fatally
              return true;
          }
    }
    catch( std::exception& e ) { // catch allocation exceptions.
        std::stringstream errstr;
        errstr << "Exception in thread: " << e.what();
        std::string logentry = errstr.str();
        errstr.str("");
        GDLogger.log( logentry, 3 );
    }
}
```

which is called from inside:

```
void session( socket_ptr sock ) { // the actual TCP session starts here
    bool inproc = false; // this will be set to true once input has been sucessfully processed.
    try {
        GDLogger.log( "Connection Established.", 1 );
        int icont = 0;
        for( ; ;) {
            char data[max_length];
            boost::system::error_code error;
            size_t length = sock->read_some( boost::asio::buffer( data ), error ); // reads the length of the buffer, then reads the buffer into the char* data
            char cdata[max_length];
            for( int i = 0; i < max_length; i++ ) {
                cdata[i] = data[i];
            }
            std::vector<int> idata; // our hero, the vector going into handle_data
            idata.resize( max_length );
            idata = sanData( cdata ); // sanitize
            bool dvalid = valSerialData( idata ); // validate
            if( !dvalid ) {
                GDLogger.log("Data rejected by server.", 3 );
            }
            if( dvalid ) {
                GDLogger.log("Valid Datastream accepted. Processing.", 1 );
                inproc = handle_data( idata );
            }
            if( inproc == true && error == boost::asio::error::eof ) { // if EOF reached and
                GDLogger.log( "Connection Terminated, data processed.", 1 ); // if handle_data success, close connection
                break;
            }
            else if( !inproc && error == boost::asio::error::eof && icont > 0) {
                GDLogger.log( "Connection Terminated before data was successfully processed.", 2 );
                break;
            }
            else if( error ) {
                throw boost::system::system_error( error ); //some other error
            }
            icont++; // to ensure that handle_data only gets called ONCE
        }
    }
    catch( std::exception& e ) {
        std::stringstream errstr;
        errstr << "Exception in thread: " << e.what() << "\n";
        std::string logentry = errstr.str(); // catch all the lovely boost errors
        errstr.str("");
        GDLogger.log( logentry, 3 );
    }
    GDLogger.log( "Thread Exited.", 0 );
}
```

the place it complains about is another module, the drive module, which reads serialized drive data:

```
bool ddrive::readDriveData( const vector<int> &data1 ) {
    GDLogger.log( "readDriveData() called.", 0 );
    int SequenceNumber = 0;
    vector<bool> validated;
    vector<bool> dbadded;
    vector<bool> rval;
    GDLogger.log( "Resizing vectors.", 0 );
    rval.resize(Ddnum);
    dbadded.resize( Ddnum );
    validated.resize( Ddnum );
    for( int i = 0; i < Ddnum; i++ ) {
        GDLogger.log( "Setting rval to false...", 0 );
        rval[i] = false;
    }
    for( int i = 0; i < Ddnum; i++ ) {
        for( int j = 0; j < vdlen; j++ ) {
            Ddcode[j] = data1[SequenceNumber];
            std::stringstream ff;
            ff << "SN: "<< SequenceNumber << " " << Ddcode[j];
            std::string mmm = ff.str();
            ff.str("");
            GDLogger.log( mmm, 0 );
            SequenceNumber++;
        }
        std::stringstream lstr;
        lstr << "Sequence Number: " << SequenceNumber;
        std::string logm = lstr.str();
        lstr.str("");
        GDLogger.log( logm, 0 );
        Ddpath = mapp.getKeyFromMap( Ddcode[0], Ddcode[1], 3 );
        Dspnum = readSpoolNumber( Ddcode[2], Ddcode[3] );
        Dhstatus = readDHState( Ddcode[4] );
        Dspfill = read3DigitVals( Ddcode[5], Ddcode[6], Ddcode[7] );
        Dspstate = readSpoolState( Ddcode[8] );
        Dpsec = read3DigitVals( Ddcode[9], Ddcode[10], Ddcode[11] );
        Drsec = read3DigitVals( Ddcode[12], Ddcode[13], Ddcode[14] );
        bool DDValid = true;
        if( DDValid ) {
            validated[i] = true;
            GDLogger.log( "Converting data to strings for database insertion.", 1 );
            std::stringstream qq;
            qq << Ddcode[2] << Ddcode[3];
            std::string qspnum = qq.str();
            GDLogger.log( qspnum, 0 );
            qq.str("");
            qq << Dspfill;
            std::string qspfill = qq.str();
            GDLogger.log( qspfill, 0 );
            qq.str("");
            qq << Dpsec;
            std::string qpsec = qq.str();
            GDLogger.log( qpsec, 0 );
            qq.str("");
            qq << Drsec;
            std::string qrsec = qq.str();
            GDLogger.log( qrsec, 0);
            qq.str("");
            GDLogger.log( Dhsname, 0 );
            qdata[0] = Dhsname;
            qdata[1] = Ddpath;
            qdata[2] = qspnum;
            qdata[3] = Dhstatus;
            qdata[4] = qspfill;
            qdata[5] = Dspstate;
            qdata[6] = qpsec;
            qdata[7] = qrsec;
            GDLogger.log( Dhsname, 0);
            GDLogger.log( Ddpath, 0 );
            dbadded[i] = thread.runDriveQuery( qdata ); // this is where it complains
        }
        else {
            GDLogger.log( "Drive datastream rejected by server.", 3 );
            validated[i] = false;
        }
    }
    bool valid = true;
    bool dbadd = true;
    GDLogger.log( "Validating that operation performed successfully.", 1 );
    for( int i = 0; i < Ddnum; i++ ) {
        if( !validated[i] ) {
            valid = false;
        }
        if( !dbadded[i] ) {
            dbadd = false;
        }
    }
    if( dbadd && valid ) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I realized what Anton had been saying while I was sleeping, and did as he said, and instead changed function drive::readDriveData so that it would take an instance of dbase as a parameter like so:

```
bool ddrive::readDriveData( const vector<int> &data1, dbase db );
```

And it compiles. I'll see what happens now.

Comment: `dbase thread;` - if this line is just written in cpp file then you have one global `dbase` object

Comment: Was about to ask similar. Do all the threads shared the same instance of `dbase` object? (named `thread`) ? Instances of that class look anything-but thread-safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one global `dbase` object:

```
extern dbase thread; // in h file
dbase thread; // in cpp file
```

It's shared between threads, so it has to be thread safe, but it is not.

EDIT: If you create dbase object inside the thread function (which is right), remove `extern dbase thread;` from h file, because you don't have global object anymore, otherwise you'll get linker error.

Comment: when I declare the dbase object inside the thread, my compiler refuses to link, saying 'undefined reference to 'thread', even though it is defined inside main.o :(

Comment: @Oblivious12 show in your question how exactly you do it.

Comment: I've updated to show where and how it's instantiated.

Comment: @Oblivious12 remove `extern dbase thread` from h file - check updated answer

Comment: @Oblivious12 after you removed `extern dbase thread;` from h file and `dbase thread;` from cpp file, where else do you have `dbase` objects declared/instantiated?

Comment: nowhere, but drive still needs to use it, and it says it's undefined, because it's not been defined anywhere where drive (a seperate cpp file) can see it:
obj/drive.o: In function `ddrive::readDriveData(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)':
/home/ianc/www/coding/GDAgent/include/drive.cpp:125: undefined reference to `thread'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: e.g. dbadded[i] = thread.runDriveQuery( qdata ); is where it is being used and it's complaining, which is in my question

Comment: @Oblivious12 if it "didn't know" about `thread`, it would give a compile error like "undeclared identifier". The `thread` is declared somewhere for sure. And it shouldn't be. So as long is `thread` is now defined in the thread function, you have to pass it as parameter to any functions which are using it.

Comment: what do you mean 'now defined in the thread function' - I moved 'dbase thread;' to the thread function and removed it from both dbase.h and dbase.cpp and it still comaplains

Comment: @Oblivious12 Look, after you delete global `thread` variable you say you have it defined only in `handle_data()` function. But now you have a different function, `ddrive::readDriveData()`, which also accesses a variable with the name `thread`. The question is: how this function knows about it? It has no access to variables declared in `handle_data()`. If this variable wasn't declared in global scope or maybe as static member of class `ddrive`, it would be COMPILE ERROR, not LINKER ERROR.